# Checkbox Required Validator

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, checkbox

I have developing an app in asp.net, on my page there is checkbox which is required field and I code following validation but on pressing save validation is not calling.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkContent" runat="server" Text=" I hereby certify that the information above is true and accurate."
                        Font-Bold="true" />
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="Custom1"  CssClass="errorTop" ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxValidation" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="You must select this box to proceed" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

and the save button code is

```
   <asp:Button ID="BtnSaveMiscDetail" ValidationGroup="AddMisc" CssClass="buttonGrid"
                            runat="server" Text="Save" Width="60px" OnClick="BtnSaveMiscDetail_Click" />
```

Client Side Validation code is

```
function CheckBoxValidation(oSrouce, args) {
        var myCheckBox = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_MiscDetails1_ChkContent");

        if (myCheckBox.checked) {

            args.IsValid = true;

        }
        else
            args.IsValid = false;

    }
```

validation function is not calling.

Comment: Add `ValidationGroup="AddMisc"` in your custom validator control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ValidationGroup="AddMisc"` in your custom validator control.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ChkContent" runat="server" Text=" I hereby certify that the information above is true and accurate."
                        Font-Bold="true" />
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="Custom1" 
                          CssClass="errorTop" 
                          ClientValidationFunction="CheckBoxValidation" 
                          runat="server"
                          ErrorMessage="You must select this box to proceed"
                          ValidationGroup="AddMisc">
                    </asp:CustomValidator>
```